# Access control - coding to the activity

Tags: php, access-control

Consider (from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Access_Control_Cheat_Sheet):

```
if (AC.hasAccess(ARTICLE_EDIT)) {
  //execute activity
}
```

This correctly implies that access control

> ... policy is persisted/centralized in some way

My question is around how best to centralise this.

One obvious way I can think of is to include all activities needing access control in a class - hardcoding.  I can simply call the method `hasAccess(ARTICLE_EDIT)` on this class.  This implies that whenever an activity is added to the application I need to add it to the class.

Another way to centralise access control might be to include controlled activities in my database.  Each time I need to check access I call `hasAccess(ARTICLE_EDIT)` and this would trigger a call to my database. I would include the method in the access control model.

Firstly, am I an the right track please?  Are there any other solutions people favour?  What might be the benefits/issues of solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting the "externalized access control" issue. It's great that you've thought of decoupling the business logic from the auhthorization logic. Now you need a way to express your authorization logic.

There is a standard for that called XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language:

- [standard homepage](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml)
- [definition & architecture](http://www.axiomatics.com/pure-xacml.html)
- [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML)). With XACML, you can define access control policies centrally. You maintain an external policy decision point (PDP) which evaluates incoming XACML requests againt the set of known policies.

A sample policy looks like the following using the XACML ALFA notation:

```
namespace example{
    policy article{
        target clause itemType=="article"
        apply firstApplicable
        rule editArticle{
            target clause actionId == "edit" and userRole == "editor"
            permit
            condition userId == owner
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @david - an XACML implementation exists for PHP (https://github.com/enygma/xacmlphp), but this is probably too much for my needs.  I will use a cut down version of the standard though, with the thought that I can revisit later.